# converting javascript to exe, WScript has not been declared

Tags: javascript, windows, jscript

We have a `javascript` that i would like to compile to a `exe`.

I am using the `jsc.exe` to do this. However, i get the following error when attempting to compile.

```
error JS1135: Variable 'WScript' has not been declared
```

Here is the segment of code:

```
var omgShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" );
```

What is the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the solution at this link? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/netfxjscript/thread/6f6846e1-80ac-49cd-8f79-07c44f717c3c they reccommend `new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");` instead of `WScript.CreateObject`

Comment: I saw that, but i didn't think it was related to my issue. lol. I will give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: What about everywhere else that i am using WScript? For instance `WScript.Echo(...);`. I know very little about the `javascript` world, just trying to get this script to work. =)

Comment: I actually just realized that the problem i was having was unrelated to this. I no longer need to compile it to `exe`. I got everything to compile with the above mentioned suggestions of `new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");`. I also changed all my references of `WScript` to `omgShell` and it seemed to work. But i figured out that was not the problem at all and just solved my other problem. Please post this as the answer CMP and i will accept it, as it was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WScript is a variable that is not available in the context of jsc.exe. See [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/netfxjscript/thread/6f6846e1-80ac-49cd-8f79-07c44f717c3c) for more info.

In your case simply use `var omgShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");`, and replace all references to `WScript` with `omgShell`

or simply do `var WScript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");`

Answer (score 3):

JScript.NET is not the same thing as WSH. You will need to modify your code to use the .NET objects instead of the WSH objects.